# Android another Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Everyone knows that when you are manipulating with Database you should do that in another `Thread`. But I don't understand is that really necessary when you are just inserting one item for example, or when it is happening when user opens `Activity` or `Fragment` for example and data is just loading from Database you user would wait for loading ending whatever.
Maybe it even stops app a bit while creating new Thread ect.
So what do you think is that "must be" to create new Threads?

Comment: If your main thread remains busy elsewhere, and not serve new screen refreshes of UI, the UI will appear to stutter. Also, if android detects that UI freezes too much (say more than 5 seconds), system is going to show ANR (app not responding) error. So, leave main thread free for UI serving.

Answer (score 1):

A thread should be used in a long running process that would block the UI from updating. If it's more than a second or two you might want to put it into a background thread and notify the user with a dialog or spinner or something. If you lock the UI thread for more than 5 seconds the user will be prompted with a kill or wait option by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

To have a good user experience heavy works should run in another thread, in this way there aren't any lags or blocks and the user experience is better.

The time taken to create a new thread is a lot less than the time taken to performe a query or an http request or other heavy works. Maybe on your phone this time is short but on low level phone it can take more time. After 5s Android shows to the user an allert to ask if user wants kill the app or wait, this isn't good.

Another point, it's true that the user must wait data to use it BUT if you performe a request in main thread the view will blocked, if you do it in another thread thed view is smooth, you can show easy a progress bar and if user want return back the app still responsive.

I can understand that send messages beetwen threads isn't easy like do it in main thread, but if you use a bus, like OTTO Bus (http://square.github.io/otto/) and extend the bus class in this way

> public class AndroidBus extends Bus{

```
private final Handler mainThread = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

@Override
public void post(final Object event) {
    if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        super.post(event);
    } else {
        mainThread.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                post(event);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

In this way u can easly send messages beetwen threads